# Rust Futures for String

Tags: asynchronous, rust, async-await, rust-tokio

I've been trying to understand and play with `futures` (version 0.3) but couldn't make this work. As I understand, a function is able to return a future of type `A` only if the type `A` implements the future trait. If I create a struct and implement the future trait, it's okay but why `String` doesn't work?

```rust
use futures::prelude::*;

async fn future_test() -> impl Future<Output=String> {
    return "test".to_string();
}
```

I get the error:

```
the trait bound `std::string::String: core::future::future::Future` is not satisfied

the trait `core::future::future::Future` is not implemented for `std::string::String`

note: the return type of a function must have a statically known sizerustc(E0277)
```

So I told myself, okay then I can use `Box` like:

```rust
async fn future_test() -> impl Future<Output=Box<String>> {
    return Box::new("test".to_string());
}
```

But the error is same:

```
the trait bound `std::string::String: core::future::future::Future` is not satisfied

the trait `core::future::future::Future` is not implemented for `std::string::String`

note: the return type of a function must have a statically known sizerustc(E0277)
```

What am I doing wrong? And why does the future hold the `String` instead of the `Box` itself?

Comment: `async fn` automatically wraps the return type in a future for you, so you should change the signature to just `async fn future_test() -> String`.

Comment: @apetranzilla Okay but what if I don't use async?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Async functions are automatically compiled to futures regardless of whether they actually use await or not, so `async fn hello() -> String { "hello".to_string() }` would compile to a function returning `impl Future<Output=String>` that will immediately complete when polled.

Comment: @apetranzilla I mean why writing it manually won't compile?

Comment: @GManNickG Yeah I've read but what I mean is explained here: https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/03_async_await/01_chapter.html#async-lifetimes

But I guess it doesn't work because I don't supply a lifetime parameter and don't move the function to an async block.

Comment: if you want to write it manually, you need to remove the `async` qualifier. The function would then be `fn hell() -> impl Future<Output=String> { /* ... */ }`. The actual type implementing `Future` would be something you'd have to write by hand or import from another crate (like `futures`); the compiler has special support to generate futures from `async fn`s that can't be fully replicated manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a function is declared `async`, it implicitly returns a future, with the return type of the function as its `Output` type. So you would write this function:

```rust
async fn future_test() -> String {
    "test".to_string()
}
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to explicitly specify return type as a `Future`, you would drop the `async` keyword. If you did that you would also need to construct a future to return, and you would not be able to use `await` inside the function.

```rust
fn future_test2() -> impl Future<Output=String> {
    ready("test2".to_string())
}
```

Note that `futures::ready` constructs a Future that is immediately ready, which is appropriate in this case since there is no actual asynchronous activity going on in this function.

[Link to Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5cda7e07df085470c72ec4e154d9bcbf)

Comment: I don't have to use lifetime parameters, it makes sense now. Thanks!